Qemu unable to unlock ram - bridge not found
I'm trying to boot a Linux kernel in qemu.
$ qemu-system-x86_64 \
 -kernel ./linux-stable/vmlinux \
 -M q35 \
 -initrd initramfs.cpio.gz \
 -drive file=./hd,if=virtio,format=raw \
 -nographic \
 --append "root=/dev/vda console=tty0 console=ttyS0" \
 -vga none \
 -display none \
 -debugcon file:debug.log -global isa-debugcon.iobase=0x402 $@

Qemu gets stuck booting from ROM.
SeaBIOS (version 1.15.0-1)


iPXE (https://ipxe.org) 00:01.0 C000 PCI2.10 PnP PMM+07F8B0D0+07ECB0D0 C000



Booting from ROM..

The debug.log shows this repeating message.
In resume (status=0)
In 32bit resume
Attempting a hard reboot
Unable to unlock ram - bridge not found

My environment (WSL2 Ubuntu)
$ uname -r
5.15.167.4-microsoft-standard-WSL2

$ qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 6.2.0 (Debian 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.24)
Copyright (c) 2003-2021 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

$ file ./linux-stable/vmlinux
./linux-stable/vmlinux: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=4b53daf1502c032d1d61d069c7e7f5d432c03b8e, with debug_info, not stripped


Is /dev/vda partitioned?  Normally, root line should read root=/dev/vdaX where X is the partition where the / filesystem resides?
